# Programming Query for adding a Xelement or removing a xelement in Xelement file in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

i have the following XML file...

```
<TrebuchetWorkspaceTemplate>
 <InputDocument>
  <BusinessDocument>
   <BusinessRequirement />
   <ProcessModel />
  </BusinessDocument>
  <FunctionalDocuments />
  <UseCases />
  <Agile />
</InputDocument>
<Miscellaneous />
</TrebuchetWorkspaceTemplate>
```

Now what code can I write if I want 
1) to find any particular XElement say    "< BusinessRequirement/>"
2) add another new xelement child to it
3) also find any Xelement in xml file for removing it..

will be helpful if u reply with specific answers....or any pre existing code....Thanks once again for previous answers...

Answer (score 3):

> Now what code can I write if I want 1) to find any particular XElement say `<BusinessRequirement/>`

Well,

```
var element = doc.Descendants("BusinessRequirement").First();
```

will find the *first* such element - but what do you want to do if there aren't any? Or if there are multiple?

> 2) add another new xelement child to it

Call `Add` afterwards:

```
element.Add(new XElement("foo"));
```

> 3) also find any Xelement in xml file for removing it.

Call `Remove`:

```
element.Remove();
```

You should have been able to find all of these out by using a good tutorial or book on LINQ to XML though - you shouldn't try to learn a new technology just by asking questions here; it's important to learn it systematically, with a good guide. LINQ to XML is a *wonderful* API, but you really need to get to know its idioms.

I suggest you start off with the MSDN [LINQ to XML main page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: thanks  a lot jon....actually have no time for reading books....i work 12-14 hrs a day in office....this is my only option of resolving queries....will be helpful if u keep helpin me...

Comment: @Brijraj: Absolutely not. That's a *terrible* attitude. You *must* do research yourself in future. Stack Overflow isn't meant to be an *alternative* to research; it's meant to be *complementary* to it. You'll find that if you spend more time learning things properly, you'll save huge amounts of time in the long run.

Comment: Say if I have a  XmlDocument Tra= new XmlDocument(); and I want to find a particular XmlElement in that ...how can I find it?